# Using testthat with more than one expected outcome

Tags: r, unit-testing, automated-tests, devtools, r-package

I wish to check an R function that may output one of two acceptable values using the "testthat" package.  Here's a simplified example:

```r
Foo <- function () {
  if (uncontrolable_condition) {
    matrix(as.raw(0x0c))
  } else {
    matrix(as.raw(0x03))
  }
}
```

The best solution I could come up with is

```
result <- Foo()
expect_true(identical(result, matrix(as.raw(0x0c))) ||
            identical(result, matrix(as.raw(0x03))))
```

But this loses the functionality of `waldo::compare`: if I fail the test,
I have to manually run `waldo::compare(Foo(), matrix(as.raw(0x0c)))` to see how the output differs from the expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need a custom expectation. Based on the [testthat pkgdown site](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/custom-expectation.html), it might look something like this:

```r
expect_options <- function(object, options) {
  
  # 1. Capture object and label
  act <- quasi_label(rlang::enquo(object), arg = "object")
  
  # 2. Call expect()
  compResults <- purrr::map_lgl(options, ~identical(act$val, .x))
  expect(
    any(compResults),
    sprintf(
      "Input (%s) is not one of the accepted options: %s",
            toString(act$val),
            paste(purrr::map_chr(options, toString), collapse = ", ")
    )
  )
  
  # 3. Invisibly return the value
  invisible(act$val)

}

expect_options(result, list(matrix(as.raw(0x0c)), matrix(as.raw(0x03))))
```